# Do I need a separate object for every @RequestBody in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

So far I have done one (REST) project using Spring Boot and liked it a lot.   The one thing I found to be somewhat devious was my understanding of `@RequestBody`.

Suppose I have the POST method below to login a user. My user entity may contain attributes other than just the username and password I'd like the post-request to have. In this case I saw no other option but to make an extra object (LoginRequest) to hold the data for the incoming data.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
        User p = null;
        if (request != null) {
            p = User.login(request.getEmail(), request.getPassword()); // validates and returns user if exists
            if (p != null){
                return new ResponseEntity<User>(p, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password or email incorrect");
    }
```

Similarly, I'd like the `@ResponseBody` to return a minimized version of the User object where for example the password is excluded.

What are some of the standard approaches to this issue? Do I really have to make a separate object for every 'json-view'? I did some REST stuff in python before and here I would just have a Dictionary containing the request attributes. Any similar approaches?

Comment: Do you want to ignore some attribute's value in return to view or as request to read for same class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a new entity if you will persist or operate on it
2. If you need a custom view for existing entity (add/remove fields) DTO with custom serialization can be used
3. There maybe a case when you don't want to create DTO because you will not reuse it anywhere, but need some quick solution for custom response you can use Map<String, Object> - the key will be used for JSON field name, and Object is for the value, for example:

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public Map<String, Object> login(@RequestParam Integer p1) {
   Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put("p1", p1);
   map.put("somethingElse", "456");
   return map;
   }

JSON response:

```
{
  "p1": p1value,
  "somethingElse": "456"
}
```

3rd case will suite you if you're not building too complex bodies with nested objects which should be customized based on some conditions. Use 2nd option in the opposite case.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches to this, for both Request and Response -
1. Use Same entities with extra params and populate only what you need. You can check for nulls.
2. Use separate Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) - These basically can be used when entities have different fields than the object you need to transfer.

Personally, I like the first approach to save the effort of mapping entities to DTOs and back. But, sometimes when DTOs need to be totally different, we need to use the second approach. Eg. APIs for dashboards numbers and reports.

HTH

Comment: Not using spring but a similar framework.  I settled on using a DTO where each attribute was a String (even if it would end up being a number or Date or something else on the entity). Beacuse I wanted to be able to re-display invalid entries if validation failed.  If I had a field mapped as a Date and the user input 'xyz' and I re-display the form with validation errors, I want to be able to show the bad value and let them edit it.  Not just lose it.  Not sure if Spring would have that same problem?

Comment: @NicholasSmith That sounds more like you should've had front end validation. Server side validation is then for someone intentionally trying to pass wrong data (such as sending an invalid request through curl).

Comment: Yes I'm not sure if he's doing client or server side validation that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: @NicholasSmith I was referring to what you did. Doing both client and server side validation has plenty of advantages. Obviously wrong requests not even going to the server, the server doing validation for security and getting strongly typed data automatically instead of using Strings for params...

Comment: Client side validations should be present, but even if a server-side validation fails, you should always return an http bad request instead of 200. You can have the DTO sending back array of messages (errors/warnings etc) which can be shown on the client form. Ofcourse, since it is ajax, with server error, the client side form will stay with the old values and display the message server passed back. The user can then update the "bad" values again.